# Failed to create JVM

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have updated my android studio and also updated java to 1.8.0_51. I have also increased the environmental variable Xmx512M(through control panel by adding _JAVA_OPTIONS). Now, when I am trying to open Android Studio, it is showing this error

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding the Java path to environmental variables

Answer (score 0):

You should install 64-bit JDK instead of 32-bit